# How to set SBCL's current directory using slime?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

In the past, i use the following script to start SBCL:

```
breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''|\\"
cd /media/E/work

exec rlwrap --remember -c -b "$breakchars"  -f "$HOME"/.sbcl_completions  sbcl --noinform --userinit "$HOME"/.sbclrc "$@"
```

Now when using slime in emacs, i doonot know how to set SBCL's current directory ?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to change the current directory from SLIME? I assume it's not because you want to visit a Lisp source file from the system you're currently writing, but because you want write code that reads or writes a file that contains data.

If so, it's probably better to try [`local-projects`](http://blog.quicklisp.org/2011/11/november-quicklisp-updates.html) in [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/). Together with [`quickproject`](https://github.com/xach/quickproject), it allows you to easily create systems, which you can then load using `(ql:quickload 'my-system)` or even `(require 'my-system)`.

If you need to refer to a data file located relative to the root of system `my-system` (just using the name from the last paragraph to keep examples consistent), you could use [`asdf:system-relative-pathname`](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Miscellaneous-additional-functionality.html). For instance, `(asdf:system-relative-pathname 'my-system "files/data.txt")`.

Sure, deployment is a completely different business. My solution is to look at [how the running executable was called](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Command_002dline-arguments.html) to determine if the code is deployed or in development. If in development, I use `asdf:system-relative-pathname`. If deployed, I determine the path of the files based on the path of the executable (my 'build script' copies these files next to the executables when building the project).

Since I started using this approach, my need for `cd`-ing in SBCL dropped to zero. `cd`-ing around wasn't hard, but it's nice to have less things to worry about.

Answer (score 13):

SLIME starts the Lisp system with the current directory taken from the directory where the file associated with the current buffer is. Typically you would open a file where you want SLIME to start first.

If you want to change the current directory in a running Lisp then the best way is to use [,cd shortcut](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Shortcuts.html). This assumes you have a proper slime-repl set up, since current Slime installations are very minimal by default. See [contributed packages](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Contributed-Packages.html), you probably want at least [slime-fancy metapackage](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/slime_002dfancy.html#slime_002dfancy).

Comment: slime-cd is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `slime.el'.

(slime-cd DIRECTORY)

Make DIRECTORY become Lisp's current directory.
Return whatever swank:set-default-directory returns.

Comment: This was helpful. However, the link to "cd shortcut" is dead. What did you have in mind?